# Check that KeyUpEvent is a space in GWT

Tags: gwt, space, keycode

I notice from the tutorial that normally KeyUpEvent event is checked by comparing getNativeKeyCode with KeyCodes. But KeyCodes only has constants for special keys and none of the characters. Is there a way to get around hard-coding the value for spacebar (which appears to be "32")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write this code to close the popup panel with checking spacebar (32) and it works for me

```
   @Override
    protected void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);
        if(event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 32){ // spacebar
            hide();
        }   
    }
```

KeyUpEvent also has getNativeEvent();

that you can check with the same way

```
KeyUpEvent k;
k.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == 32
```

Comment: thanks for your answer - i was wondering if there was a way around magic numbers. kinda like how there's keycodes.key_alt for instance

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the char for space to compare against, like this:

```
if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == ' ') {
   // special logic here 
}
```